# Using TouchId get null Ti. objects

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, touch-id

I am trying to implement TouchId into my app, but am having some issues.

Here is the function I am using, straight from the documentation:

```
function SignInTouchID(){
TiTouchId.authenticate({
    reason: 'We need your fingerprint to sign in.',
    callback: function(e) {
        if (!e.success) {
            //alert('Message: ' + e.error + '\nCode: ' + e.code);
            switch(e.code) {
                case TiTouchId.ERROR_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED: Ti.API.info('Error code is TiTouchId.ERROR_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED'); break;
                case TiTouchId.ERROR_USER_CANCEL: Ti.API.info('Error code is TiTouchId.ERROR_USER_CANCEL'); break;
                case TiTouchId.ERROR_USER_FALLBACK: Ti.API.info('Error code is TiTouchId.ERROR_USER_FALLBACK'); break;
                case TiTouchId.ERROR_SYSTEM_CANCEL: Ti.API.info('Error code is TiTouchId.ERROR_SYSTEM_CANCEL'); break;
                case TiTouchId.ERROR_PASSCODE_NOT_SET: Ti.API.info('Error code is TiTouchId.ERROR_PASSCODE_NOT_SET'); break;
                case TiTouchId.ERROR_TOUCH_ID_NOT_AVAILABLE: Ti.API.info('Error code is TiTouchId.ERROR_TOUCH_ID_NOT_AVAILABLE'); break;
                case TiTouchId.ERROR_TOUCH_ID_NOT_ENROLLED: Ti.API.info('Error code is TiTouchId.ERROR_TOUCH_ID_NOT_ENROLLED'); break;
                default: Ti.API.info('Error code is unknown'); break;
            }
        } else {    
            //alert(Ti.Platform.osname);
            //SignIn(true);
            var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
            xhr.timeout = 30000;
        }
    }
});
```

}

User clicks the login button which calls SignInTouchID. I get the fingerprint prompt and that works but once it runs the callback and execute the xhr code (inserted for brevity) I get the following error:

[image]

Its almost like it loses the Ti context.  If I remove the TouchId code I have none of these problems. Not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated!

TiSDK:5.5.1 GA
iPhone 6 v10.1.1
Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.8.0.201610171310
(c) Copyright 2012-2016 by Appcelerator, Inc.  All rights reserved.

Build: jenkins-appcelerator-rcp-release-595 (origin/release)
Date: 17 October 2016, 13:11:46

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code to this:

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    timeout: 30000
});
```

Comment: That might fix the issue for this particular line of code but the problem is bigger than that. For some reason the xhr object is null when using TouchId, not sure why that is.